# Git stage hunk error "patch does not apply" even with no changes made to the patch

Tags: git

I was getting the "patch does not apply" error while trying to manually edit a hunk. I checked for the solution to this problem and I realized I also have to change the line numbers of the hunk. Since this did not solve my problem I tried saving the hunk without any changes. Strangely, this resulted in the same error. Has anyone experienced the same problem before?